# Variable cannot fetch values from a Select Option even if name is correct

Tags: php, ajax, html-select

So I am making an assignment program wherein in my database, I have a set of documents and when I want to tag it to a person, I would choose who I will tag it to. Here is the code for assigning a person to a document.

```
<select name="staff" value="staff" align="left" onchange="senddocu(this)">
    <option selected value="">Staff</option>
    <option name='chief' value='chief'>Chief User</option>
    <option name='user' value='user'>User 1</option>
</select>
```

Now, I have a problem with getting values from another file in my PHP code. Somehow, it doesn't fetch the values from my select options. Here are the parameters for my select options. And also, my code from earlier and this code is in one file only.

```
<select name="document" align="left">
<option selected disabled value="">Document Type</option>
                            <option value="A">A</option>
                            <option value="C">C</option>
                            <option value="CO">CO</option>
                            <option value="Curr">Curr</option>
                            <option value="Scholarship">Scholarship</option>
                            <option value="MIS">MIS</option>
                            <option value="Fax">Fax</option>
                            <option value="E-mail">E-mail</option></select>

<input type="text" name= "datenow" id = "copy" align="center">
<input type="text" name="application" align="center" size = "3%">
```

And here is the code to fetch the values from those. This is in another file.

```
<?php
$document_type= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['document']);
$application_no= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['application']);
$today = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['datenow']);

echo $document_type;
echo $application_no;
echo $today;
?>
```

The problem is, only the `$today` variable fetches its value. The rest doesn't get stored into the variables from another file.It doesn't make sense at all. All the names are correct, yet its not fetching it.  I already have the ajax code on my first file which is:

```
function senddocu(sel)
{
 $.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    data: {staff: $(sel).val()},
    url: "send.php",             
    dataType: "html",            
    success: function(response)
    {                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        console.log(response);
    }

}); 
}
```

how to fetch the values?

Comment: `<select>` takes `<option>` as children, not `<input>`

Comment: None of this code makes sense. It does not seem like a complete example. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Tip: Make sure the code in your question is complete enough for us to test it or at least see how the parts interact, like, is there a form involved here? Pro tip: If there is an html form (and there should be, I think, 
 otherwise you just have to write a complete Javascript replacement for all this awesome built-in functionality), test the server side handling of it without Ajax, and maybe even without the client side form, but using a tool like Postman. And if you don't have a form, this still applies btw.

Comment: I understand. Sorry for making the information incomplete.

Comment: What's the update on this? Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct way to fetch the value of the `<select>` in your AJAX request. You need to give the select an id, or a name, which you target in order to get the right element. You then ask it for the selected options value.
In order to get the input field variables, you can select them by name, or by id also. I'm just going to do it by name, since that's what you have in your example snippet.

Example using id:

```
function senddocu()
{
 $.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    data: {
            staff: $("#sel option:selected").val(),
            datenow: $("input#datenow").val(),
            application: $("input#application").val()
          },
    url: "send.php",             
    dataType: "html",            
    success: function(response)
    {                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        console.log(response);
    }

  }); 
}
```

This example takes the selected value of a select that has the id sel. In order to make this work, you simply have to give your select the proper id.

Like so:

```
<select name="document" id="sel" align="left" onchange="senddocu();">
   <option selected disabled value="">Document Type</option>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
   <option value="CO">CO</option>
   <option value="Curr">Curr</option>
   <option value="Scholarship">Scholarship</option>
   <option value="MIS">MIS</option>
   <option value="Fax">Fax</option>
   <option value="E-mail">E-mail</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name= "datenow" id = "copy" align="center">
<input type="text" name="application" align="center" size = "3%">
```

Example by using name to get the value:

```
function senddocu(sel)
{
   $.ajax({   
     type: "POST",
     data: {
        staff: $("select[name=document] option:selected").val(),
        datenow: $("input[name=datenow]").val(),
        application: $("input[name=application]").val()
     },
     url: "send.php",             
     dataType: "html",            
     success: function(response)
     {                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        console.log(response);
     }       
  });
}
```

If the input variables are in a completely different file, you'll have to reconsider what you're trying to achieve and maybe rework your logic around that, whether there's really a reason for that. You should also consider including more coherent code in your questions so that people can get the whole picture, as well as test the code. Makes it a lot easier that way.

Comment: It got the select option to work, now the inputs which is $today and $application_no does not fetch their values. Should I make a separate ajax request for those too?

Comment: What is it 'exactly' you're trying to achieve? Do you want to fetch $today and $application from another file, get the select value from your current file, then post all of that to a 3rd file?

Comment: I just need those 3 values to be displayed on the same file where I tried to fetch them. On the "echo" code. Right there.

Comment: See edited answer, is that what you were looking for?